# homebrew on Apple Silicon M1 always got any installed app to crash with 137 exit code

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I found this blog post in Homebrew
https://brew.sh/2021/02/05/homebrew-3.0.0/

That it's not natively supported for Apple M1

However, when i tried,
I found that, every app i installed via this Homebrew 3.0
On Apple Silicon M1

I cannot open that application

It crashed immediately
and got 137 Exit code as follow

I tried `git` and `tesseract` it both gave the same response

I don't know how to get any log for better investigation.

Please advise

[image]

Comment: Please share more details - how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

It's working after I completely uninstalled homebrew and reinstalled it.